# Why are overrides not included in download file?

Tags: 7, features

I have the problem, that some of my features are overridden and will not be updated after recreation.

For example there is one feature that needs a new dependency and the title of one view was changed. 
I want to include these changes in my feature and click on recreate. 
When i look into the download files, you can see, that the changes (dependency and view titles) are not included.

If i change the files manually, the feature has the status "Standard".

The feature includes content types, panel pages, fields, views, permissions and some strongarm variables.

Does anybody know, why my changes are not included, when recreating my features?

- Drupal v. 7.43
- Features v. 7.x-2.10

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to use drush.

```
drush fu feature_name
```

After that all files were inclduded.